# Don't understand why is my exported csv-file read-only?

Tags: python, csv, readonly

I'm using the DyMat Python-package to export variables from .mat-files to .csv.
However, the exported .csv-files are all read-only? Why is this the case and is there a solution to resolve this?

I've tried to close() the file properly or delete the file in Python but that did not work. Any other suggestions?

```
import csv, numpy, os
import DyMat

os.chdir("C:/Users/myvhove/Documents/ResultsPyDymInt/Dymola/CoupledClutches")
print(os.getcwd())

dm = DyMat.DyMatFile("dymatresfile")
print(dm.fileName)
print(dm.names())
varList = ('J1.w', 'J2.w', 'J3.w', 'J4.w')

fileName = dm.fileName + '.csv'
oFile = open(fileName, 'w', newline='')
csvWriter = csv.writer(oFile)

vDict = dm.sortByBlocks(varList)
for vList in vDict.values():
    vData = dm.getVarArray(vList)
    vList.insert(0, dm._absc[0])
    csvWriter.writerow(vList)
    csvWriter.writerows(numpy.transpose(vData))

oFile.close()
```

Comment: Python isn't doing that. If you're on Unix, check your `umask`, it's removing the write permission.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting. I didn't know that. I can't check 'umask' because I'm on Windows but there will be a windows-alternative for that I suppose.

Comment: I don't know if there is.